# pgsql return from source after insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query like below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_details;
create temp table tmp_zone_section as 
    select  
            x.id,
            x.name,
            x.address,
                              x.identification
     FROM json_to_recordset
        (arg_json)
            as x(
            
            id integer,
            name character varying,
           address character varying,
           identification character varying
         );
```

with records as (
insert into details
select id, name from temp_details
on conflict do update
set address = excluded.address
returning *
)
The above query returns every affected rows, I want to return an extra column from the source which was not part of either insert or update along with * like below

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_details;
    create temp table tmp_zone_section as 
        select  
                x.id,
                x.name,
                x.address,
                                  x.identification
         FROM json_to_recordset
            (arg_json)
                as x(
                
                id integer,
                name character varying,
               address character varying,
               identification character varying
             );

with records as (
insert into details
select id, name from temp_details
on conflict do update
set address = exluded.address
returning *, temp_details. identification
)
```

Any Idea how can it be achieved.

Thanks,

Comment: Please show us the complete code of your stored function/procedure

Comment: code updated now

Comment: Well, a common table expression ("WITH") needs one final statement after the WITH

Comment: Ye I know that....

Answer (score 0):

If I am following correctly:

```
with records as (
insert into details
select id, name from temp_details
on conflict do update
set address = exluded.address
returning *
)
SELECT 
  records.*, temp_details.identification
FROM
  records
JOIN 
   temp_details
ON
   records.id = temp_details.id
```